# jquery .post or .ajax

Tags: jquery

I need to send a request to a remote server using only jquery (no server side code allowed) and alert the remote server's response. Everything I'm reading upon Googling is telling me it can't be done. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be running into a cross-domain request problem.  So far, the best (and only?) solution is to use [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  jQuery supports this via [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  The key to jsonp is that you must pass a callback as part of the request so that when the result comes back, it may be processed.